# How to let inheritance take precedence over class properties when using a metaclass?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have posted a similar question before but I interpreted my problem wrong, so I flagged it for deletion and come forth with the new and correct problem.

My general goal is the following: I want to have a `property` on a **class**, so I implement it on a metaclass using a property as suggested on my question [Implementing a class property that preserves the docstring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22358195/1326104). Additionally, I want users to be able to subclass the base class and override this property with static values. The thing here is that if the user does not provide an attribute, I want to calculate a sensible default and since all configuration is done at the class level, I need a property at the class level.

A basic example will show this:

```
class Meta(type):
    @property
    def test(self):
        return "Meta"


class Test(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta


class TestSub(Test):
    test = "TestSub"


class TestSubWithout(Test):
    pass

print(TestSub.test, TestSubWithout.test)
```

Here is what it prints:

```
('Meta', 'Meta')
```

And what I want it to print:

```
('TestSub', 'Meta')
```

Essentially, on `TestSub` the user overrides the `test` attribute himself. Now, `TestSub` is the correct output, since the user provided it. In the case of `TestSubWithout`, the user instead did not provide the attribute and so the default should be calculated (of course, the real calculation has more than just a static return, this is just to show it).

I know what happens here: First the attribute `test` is assigned to `TestSub` and then the metaclass overrides it. But I don't know how to prevent it in a *clean and pythonic* way.

Comment: "First the attribute test is assigned to TestSub and then the metaclass overrides it." - that's not quite what happens. The `'TestSub'` value is still there in the class dict, but since `property` instances are [data descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors), a property found in the metaclass will be used in preference to a value found in the dict of the class or its ancestors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a class property with a metaclass that only overrides when the class itself doesn't have it defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462796/how-to-create-a-class-property-with-a-metaclass-that-only-overrides-when-the-cla)

Comment: @MatthewTrevor Yes that is the post I was referring to in the beginning. I didn't link it because I expect it to be deleted by a mod in favor of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `property` is a "data descriptor", which means that it takes precedence in the attribute search path over values stored in a instance dictionary (or for a class, the instance dictionaries of the other classes in its MRO).

Instead, write your own non-data descriptor that works like `property`:

```
class NonDataProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.fget = fget

    def __get__(self, obj, type):
        if obj:
            return self.fget(obj)
        else:
            return self

    # don't define a __set__ method!
```

Here's a test of it:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    @NonDataProperty
    def x(self):
        return "foo"

class Foo(metaclass=MyMeta):
    pass # does not override x

class Bar(metaclass=MyMeta):
    x = "bar" # does override x

class Baz:
    x = "baz"

class Baz_with_meta(Baz, metaclass=MyMeta):
    pass # inherited x value will take precedence over non-data descriptor

print(Foo.x) # prints "foo"
print(Bar.x) # prints "bar"
print(Baz_with_meta.x) # prints "baz"
```

Comment: What's the advantage of this over my solution? Do I miss something here? To me it seems very similar.

Comment: Your type of property won't work in the `Baz_with_meta` case. The inherited instance value will be overridden by the metaclass's property.

Comment: You are right, I read up on data- vs. non-data-descriptors. Yours works better.

Answer (score 1):

I cleanest way I could come up with is creating a subclass of `property` that handles this case:

```
class meta_property(property):
    def __init__(self, fget, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        self.key = fget.__name__
        super(meta_property, self).__init__(fget, fset, fdel, doc)

    def __get__(self, obj, type_):
        if self.key in obj.__dict__:
            return obj.__dict__[self.key]
        else:
            return super(meta_property, self).__get__(obj, type_)
```

This handles the case by storing the name of the function and returning the overridden value if it is present. This seems like an okayish solution but I am open to more advanced suggestions.

Comment: If you want inherited values to take priority over the property, this won't work. The class's value only takes effect for that specific class, not its subclasses.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't find that to be true, I tested it with multiple inheritances, it still works.

Comment: Define `class Foo(object): __metaclass__ = Meta; test = 'Foo'` and `class Bar(Foo): pass`. `Bar` doesn't inherit `Foo`'s `test` value.